# How can I capture a picture from webcam and send it via flask

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I want to send an Image object in a flask response but it gives me an error. I tried also an approach with StringIO.

```
image = Image.open("./static/img/test.jpg")
return send_file(image, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

This is just a test case. So the major problem is to capture an image from */dev/video0* and sent it (ideally without temporary storing on disk) to the client. I use [v4l2capture](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/v4l2capture/) for that. The test picture should also work if you may have a better solution for that task.

```
import select
import v4l2capture
video = v4l2capture.Video_device("/dev/video0")
size_x, size_y = video.set_format(1280, 1024)
video.create_buffers(1)
video.queue_all_buffers()
video.start()
select.select((video,), (), ())
image_data = video.read()
video.close()
image = Image.fromstring("RGB", (size_x, size_y), image_data)
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Works now. Better solutions as v4l2capture are welcome...

Comment: What is the error? What is your question? Where so you need help?

Comment: @User The error was sending an image object with flask. But I think there is a straighter solution for getting an image from /dev/video0 and send it?

Comment: What is `Image`? A class? From PIL? There are the methods [tostring](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.tostring) and [tobitmap](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.tobitmap).

Comment: @User Simple import Image, from PIL. May there other ways then `v4l2capture`?

Answer (score 0):

Did it with.

```
image = Image.open("./static/img/test.jpg")
img_io = StringIO()
image.save(img_io, 'JPEG', quality=70)
img_io.seek(0)
return send_file(img_io, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```